# Using a .vmdk file in VMware player 5.0.1

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, vmware-player

I am new to VMware player. I downloaded an OS ready for VMware player, which turned up to be a .vmdk.
I am using VMware player 5.0.1 for Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.
How will I open the file?

Comment: So what is your question here?  Are you just asking how to run this image file?

Comment: Yes, as it is not accepting it via `Use Existing Image` and I can't use a ready disk in `Create new disk`.

Comment: When you try to add an existing image, what exactly does it do? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No, it just doesn't let me use that file extension, it only uses .vmx, .ovf and .ova

Comment: Have you tried creating a new machine, and then attaching the VMDK to it as it's disk?

Comment: How? After creating virtual drive?

Comment: GUYS! Why nobody did answer this simple question? @markscamilleri just asks how to attach these .vmdk files to exiting VM. Trust me - this is not so easy for newbee as you can think. I have the same trouble!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To use exiting `.vmdk` file(-s) in VMPlayer, you should do several things:

1. Create new Virtual Machine, choose "I will install operating system later..."
2. Select prefered Guest OS
3. Customize other guest hardware settings
4. After creating this new VM, go "Edit Virtual machine settings"
5. Add new Hard disk, on the screen "Select a disk", select item "Use an exiting virtual disk" and then select your `.vmdk` file.

Comment: I have to be honest that since this was a long time ago I moved on... literally I changed programs and everything. Now I'm not even using a virtual machine. Anyway I'm gonna accept yours since you had the same problem (but I can't test it out, sorry)

Comment: This still works in VMware Workstation 12 Player :-)

Comment: On `VMware® Workstation 14 Player` (on Ubuntu 16.04) I don't see "Edit Virtual machine settings" menu. Tried mounting as well but doesn't seem to do what we want.